# Can I communicate between mac command line app to mac app

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, google-chrome-extension, message-passing

I have a mac application developed in objective - c .
there is another command line intermediate app in cpp which is native host app to receive messages from chrome extension .
whenever the intermediate app receives message from extension I want to pass that message to the mac app instantly .

Is there any message passing mechanism i can use to pass between cpp app to mac app

1. I think of writing file through cpp app & reading the same file from mac app
2. Distributed objects . but don't know it will work in cpp program
3. Any socket programming

Please suggest me any possible solution to this

Answer (score 0):

Objective C and C++ code can be combined into a single project. The solution to your question may simply be to combine the C++ native messaging host with your existing Objective C application. If these must remain separate then OS X APIs such as [Distributed Objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DistrObjects/DistrObjects.html) or other documented [alternatives](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/MacOSXNotifcationOv/AlternativestoNotification/AlternativestoNotification.html) may be the best solution for communication between these two components of your application.

Comment: I would think they will need to remain separate. The way Native Messaging works is that Chrome itself will start a new process - either for a single message or for a long-term communication channel. That "proxy" can then talk to a running program, and that was the OP's question.

Comment: Yeah if it is not made separate . i think multiple instances of the app will open!!